# numerical linear algebra reflectors

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

This is an intro to numerical linear algebra course.
I am not sure how to start with this proof.

Let $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose that $\| u \|_2 = 1$. If $P=uu^\top$, prove that

a.)$p^2=p$

b.)$p^\top = p$

Comment: What does this question have to do with reflectors?

Answer (score 1):

Just recall that 
$$\Vert u\Vert_2^2 =u^\top u$$
and 
and that 
$$(uv)^\top=v^\top u^\top$$
and the result follows easily.

Comment: for part a, it says that $\|u\|_2=1$ not $\|u\|^2_2=1$. So I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If we have $x\ge 0$ and $x^2=1$ then $x=1$.

Comment: ah okay I understand now, thanks!. Is there any chance that you can help me start with this last problem that I need.                  3.) If $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, prove that $\| Q \|_2 = \| Q^{-1} \|_2 = 1$.

Comment: I know that $QQ^\top = I$. I am not sure how I can come up with a 1 as a result.

Comment: @RenzoVallejos if you have a new question, you should really be making a new post